# Conservation of energy confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Ideal Zorro (mass $M$, no height) swings down on a vine of length $L$ from a height
$H$ and grabs a kid of mass $m$ (zero height, standing on the ground) and together
they barely reach safety at a height $h$. Relate $H$ to the other parameters. Give $H$
in meters if $L = 40m, M = 100kg, h = 6m, m = 30kg$.

The given solution states that when Zorro reaches the ground, $(1/2) Mv^2 = Mgh$.

The solution does not account for the work from the force of tension in the vine. Why not? I thought the conservation of energy says that $(1/2) mv_f^2 - (1/2)mv_i ^2 = \int F(x) dx$, where the RHS F(x) would account for both gravity and force of tension in this problem.

Also, the solution does not account for the change in mass when the kid is picked up.  Shouldn't the change in mass be considered and how should it be accounted for?

Comment: What is the angle between the tension and direction of displacement?

Comment: The problem doesn't give the angle. Do you agree that $1/2 Mv^2 = Mgh$ is incorrect?

Comment: No, it is ok. What kind of motion do you think is described here? Have you studied circular motion?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking maybe the vine moves in a circle

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes by the way. This is clearly a conceptual question about mechanics, and is a good pedagogical example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in kinetic energy is the net work done by all the forces.  Gravity is a conservative force so we define the change in potential energy as the negative of the work done by gravity.  You can include the force of gravity in your $\int_{a}^{b}\vec F \cdot d\vec x$ where $\vec F$ is the total force including gravity, or you can treat the part of the work from the force of gravity as the negative of the change in potential energy, - $mg\Delta y$, where $y$ is the elevation above ground.  It is easier to treat the work from gravity using the potential energy as it depends only on the differences in elevation regardless of how complicated the path is between the initial and final elevations.

The force of tension does no work for a rigid vine since the angle between the tension force and the displacement is always 90 degrees. Also, you can treat this problem as a simple pendulum noting that the force of tension produces no torque about the top fixed point of the vine.

I think the given solution is wrong. At the ground before Zorro picks up the kid his speed $V$ is given by ${1 \over 2} MV^2 = MgH$.  When Zorro picks up the kid his speed changes from $V$ to $ V^* = V{M \over {m + M}}$ due to conservation of linear momentum.  Then ${1 \over 2} (M + m){V^*}^2 = (M + m)gh$.  You can solve for H.

Comment: you are right $F$ is the total force including gravity. But when Zorro is swinging on the vine, there's also the force of tension. Why isn't that included in the equation from the solution is my question

Comment: I updated my answer. The force of tension does no work as discussed, assuming a rigid vine.

Comment: The vine needs to be inextensible, not rigid.

Comment: "The force of tension does no work for a rigid vine since the angle between the tension force and the displacement is always 90 degrees". Thanks that was the answer I was looking for

Comment: @nasu I think the vine cannot bend as well as not extend to keep the angle 90 degrees.

Comment: @John Darby What about the usual pendulum, with a ball attached to a string? Is the string bending?

Comment: @nasu In the evaluation of the motion of a simple pendulum, Symon Mechanics states that if a string support the mass it remains taut, otherwise we cannot treat the system as rigid one.  Taut means firm and straight like a rigid rod.

Comment: A string can be straight without being rigid.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the conservation of energy says that...

You're overthinking.  Conservation of energy says that if there's no losses, then energy stays the same.  Semantically, "conserve" *means* "stays the same".

So if you (or Zorro) change potential energy by $Mgh$, then that energy has to go *somewhere*.  If it doesn't go into heating up vines and tree branches and whatnot, then it has to go into kinetic energy.  Kinetic energy is equal to $\frac 1 2 M v^2$, so there's your relationship.

The *whole point* about the amount of attention that physicists (and engineers) put into these conservation laws is that *they make things easy*.  You don't *have* to calculate the solution to $\int F(x) \dot dx$ to get an answer.  If you know that the system is lossless, you don't even have to know $F(x)$ or $x(t)$ or anything else -- you just need to know that the energy has to go *someplace*, reason out where it has to go, and then you have your answer.

Sometime, when you have the time and the mathematical chops, you can go ahead and calculate $\vec F(\vec x)$ (yes, they're vector quantities) for Zorro swinging on a vine of length $h$.  Then you can calculate $\vec x(t)$, and you can find out what you already know* -- which is as long as the physical laws of the universe aren't changing over time**, energy is conserved.

* Thank you, again, Emily Noerther.

** Yes, yes, the universe is expanding.  **But not by much**.  You can ignore that bit.

Comment: If $1/2 Mv^2 = Mgh$ then the tension part of $\int F(x) dx$ equal $0$. I find it hard to believe this will always be $0$ and not depend on the angle $\theta$ the vine makes with the vertical.

Comment: The equation is not actually $\int F(x) dx$ unless you are only moving in one dimension. The real equation for Work is $\int \vec F \cdot d\vec x$, or the integral of the dot product of Force vector and displacement vector. The tension in the rope is always perpendicular to Zorro's displacement, so the dot product and thus the work done by the force are zero. It is a general principle that forces perpendicular to the object's displacement change its direction but not its energy (i.e. do no work on it).

Comment: "If $\frac 1 2 M v^2 = Mgh$ then ..."  No.  Just because there's tension in the vine doesn't mean that conservation of energy isn't true.  Do the math yourself and do keep in mind that you're talking about vector quantities, and also keep in mind that if conservation of energy _didn't_ work then it wouldn't be used.

Comment: @TimWescott  When Zorro picks up the kid the mass changes from M to M + m so his speed changes due to conservation of linear momentum.   So h < H. See my expanded answer.  Yes?

Comment: @RC_23 "The tension force vector is perpendicular to his displacement" Ah that makes more sense now. Thanks that was answer I was looking for

Comment: @JohnDarby: Yes.  But I felt the OP was stuck on the conservation of energy part.  Which it seems they were.

Comment: @TimWescott  Yes, that was the main concern, but I also want to point out that the given solution in the question is incorrect. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnDarby: I was assuming the given energy at the bottom of the swing was in the instant before Zorro grabbed the kid.  Yes, _afterward_ the energy would be different.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, I first thought that but the solution uses h not H; h is the final height with the kid and H is the initial height without the kid.